# Wordpress show draft pages on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i'm developing a web portal using wordpress.

I need to access draft posts from frontend.
If i login with administrator account i can view draft posts(admins posts) in single pages. But other users can't access their own drafts from frontend and gets 404 error.

The links on frontpage like http://website.com/?p=486

I'm not sure whats the problem about. Maybe **access restrictions** or **permalink settings** or **404 settings** or something else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem is single page only shows published posts.
With using wordpress [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook i changed the query and add also draft posts.

```
function ceo_single_page_published_and_draft_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_single() ) {
        $query->set('post_status', 'publish,draft');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ceo_single_page_published_and_draft_posts');
```

Comment: hi,  tried this and it isn't working, i get a blank page

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is to query for published and draft:

```
        query_posts(array(
            'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'draft')
        ));
```